# Java Collections - Effienct search for DateTime ranges

Tags: java, collections

I have a case where I have a table (t1) which contains items like

```
 | id | timestamp | att1 | att2 |
```

Now I have to iterate over a collection of elements of type att1 and get all records from t1 which are between two certain timestamps for this att1. I have to do this operation several times for a single att1.

So in order to go easy on the database queries, I intended to load every entry from t1 which has a certain att1 attribute once into a collection and perform the subsequent searches on this collection.

Is there a collection that could handle a search like *between '2011-02-06 09:00:00' and '2011-02-06 09:00:30'*? It's not guaranteed to contain entries for those two timestamps.

Before writing an implementation for that (most likely a very slow implementation ^^) I wanted to ask you guys if there might be some existing collections already or how I could tackle this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: For what particular reason can you not include the timestamp boundaries in your database query? Is the required range different for each att1 value? Even if it is, there would have to be a large volume of att1 values to check before doing a query for each becomes less efficient than getting all rows for certain att1 values and checking if these fall between bounds.

Comment: I can include the boundaries in my query - but I want to minimize the database queries. If I need to query the t1 table 125 times for a single att1, the only difference being the timestamp boundaries, it might be a lot more efficient if I just load all data once and do an in-memory search.

Comment: Ah, I missed the bit regarding multiple queries for the same att1. In that case doing it in-memory might indeed be better. It does depend on whether you know all the timestamps beforehand or not and whether you need results for particular intervals or just the set for all intervals combined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Use [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) which is basically a sorted map of key=>value pairs and its method [TreeMap::subMap(fromKey, toKey)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#subMap%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29).

In your case you would use *timestamps* as keys to the map and for values *att1* attribute or *id* or whatever else would be most convenient for you.

Comment: That's pretty cool, I didn't know about that. This is likely better than my solution :-)

Comment: Sounds good - but keep in mind that I can not guarantee to have timestamp entries that actually match the boundaries.

Comment: @chzbrgla I don't think it matters, since that is searching and filtering to select a range.

Comment: This shouldn't be the problem, it should work even if boundary values are not present.

Comment: @chzbrgla I don't think that would be a problem here. The `subMap()` method would simply use the from-to parameters to check keys in the map against. It wouldn't matter if the exact values are in there or not. Just keep in mind that the `fromKey` parameter is used in an inclusive manner, while `toKey` is used exclusive. It's a half-open interval.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can think of, and this isn't really what I would consider ideal, is to write a comparator that will sort dates so that those within the range count as less than those outside the range (always return -1 when comparing `in` to `out`, 0 when comparing `in` to `in` or `out` to `out`, and always return +1 when comparing `out` to `in`.

Then, use this comparator to sort a collection (I suggest an `ArrayList`). The values within the range will appear first.

You might just be better off writing your own filter, though. Input a collection (I recommend a `LinkedList`), iterate over it, and remove anything not in the range. Keep a master copy around for spawning new ones to pass into the filter, if you need to.

Comment: Thanks - your suggestion with the LinkedList was the implementation I was talking about in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the object you want in your collection, which I think is att1, implement the Comparable interface and then have the compareTo method compare the timestamp field.  With this in place it will work in any sorted collection, such as a treeSet, making it easy to iterate and pull out everything in a certain range.